# Sorting an NSTableColumn using transformed values

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsvaluetransformer

My class has a property which is an `enum`. This property is bound to  an `NSTableColumn`.

```
typedef enum _Status
{
    Unknown=0,
    Win,
    OSX
} Status;
```

In order to make sure that `NSTableColumn` shows the proper string representation, instead of displaying numeric 0, 1, and 2,  I use an `NSValueTransformer`.

So `Unknown` becomes "Unknown OS". `Win` becomes "MS Windows" and `OSX` becomes "OSX 10.8".  The table column displays these values correctly.

I need to sort the column using the transformed values. If I use

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"status"
                              ascending:YES
                               selector:@selector(compare:)];
```

the column is sorted in this order:

Unknown OS
MS Windows
OSX 10.8

which does make sense because 0 < 1 < 2. But I require it to be sorted using their string counterparts, which will make it:

MS Windows
OSX 10.8
Unknown OS

How can I do that without changing the order of enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the standard `compare:` method in your selector. It's just comparing the enums. Create your own method that compares the way you want.  It can call your NSValueTransformer to get the string values, and you compare those, and return the appropriate NSComparisonResult.

[edit]
OK my first suggestion won't work easily (without using categories).  But something like this should. Assuming myValueTransformer is already instantiated, and your status is an NSNumber:

```
sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"status" ascending: YES             
                                              comparator:^(id first, id second){
    NSNumber* firstNum = (NSNumber*)first;
    NSNumber* secondNum = (NSNumber*)second;
    if ([myValueTransformer transformedValue:firstNum] == [myValueTransformer transformedValue:secondNum]) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    } else if ([myValueTransformer transformedValue:firstNum] > [myValueTransformer transformedValue:secondNum]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
}];
```

Comment: From documentation "The selector must specify a method implemented by the value of the property identified by keyPath." So this means my sort descriptor will become `[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compareStatus:)]`. Am I right?

Comment: OK, my mistake. You probably don't want to do it like that then. But you can do it with a block based comparator. See my edit above.